# Using .format() with a single item tuple in pyspark spark.sql() query

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, tuples

I'm creating a set of tuples as variables to pass into a sql command. For some of them I'm needing them to be a single item tuple. I'm wanting to use tuples because there are cases where I need to combine them.

The problem is I'm getting an error when using the single tuple because it is trying to pass through the , at the end of the tuple when using .format()

```
tuple1 = (1,2,3)
tuple2 = (5,)

combo = tuple1 + tuple2

print(combo)

query = ("""

select
case
  when column in {tuple1} then 1
  when column in {tuple2} then 2
end as check

from table

where column in {combo}

""".format(tuple1 = tuple1, tuple2 = tuple2, combo = combo))

print(query)
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAFJB.png), which is returning an error due to the , coming after the 5 in the case statement.

I've tried passing it through as a string but then have problems creating the combo tuple. I've also tried creating an empty tuple and adding my value into that. Neither of these have worked so far.

Comment: Please paste the code rather than uploading as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to do `IN` then you will only ever put a tuple after it, so you can easily format on in place with [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and a comprehension which coverts the items in your tuples into `str`.

**NB.** this is SQL with string templating which allows [SQL
injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/10977). SQL injection
vulnerabilities are extremely significant, however it appears to be the only way to prepare statements for [`pyspark`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.sql.html), and even their experimental built-in "parameter" binding is simple string templating.

```py
tuple1 = (1,2,3)
tuple2 = (5,)

combo = tuple1 + tuple2

query = f"""
select
    case
        when column in ({",".join(str(v) for v in tuple1)}) then 1
        when column in ({",".join(str(v) for v in tuple2)}) then 2
    end as check
from table
where column in ({",".join(str(v) for v in combo)})
"""

print(query)
```

prints

```sql
select
    case
        when column in (1,2,3) then 1
        when column in (5) then 2
    end as check
from table
where column in (1,2,3,5)
```